# Apple's unicode keyboard layout versions location

Tags: keyboard, big-sur

Based on the "ISO" standard, say you we're to buy a keyboard and then plug it in. Note, I have never attempted this, but am assured it will work after changing your keyboard's **input** source.

Is there a location on the Mac OSX Big Sur operating system where these different key mappings are stored? Where it would be easier to program based on these files? **Where are these mapping located?**

Keyboard
Goal: (Input) American

Translated: (Other) Language

Working Example (Referenced From Comment):

I am trying to specifically translate code made in the USA in the standard format. Then run it through an AI translator which then reformats the file encoding and also the Unicode characters exactly as they were typed on a foreign computer. So the input file becomes a new file with a new file encoding standard relative to that specific country, then the characters are also changed to a specific desired Unicode standard

Or would it be best to programmatically change this?

Comment: It’s not clear to me what you are trying to do exactly.  Look at this app, which lets you easily make and install a custom layout, ansi or iso or jis, which does any language you want:  https://software.sil.org/ukelele/

Comment: @TomGewecke Thanks for the resource, I might be able to plug out some code if it is open source. But I am trying to specifically translate code made in USA in the standard format. Then run it through an AI translator which then reformats the file encoding and also the Unicode characters exactly as it were typed on a foreign computer. So an input file becomes a new file with a new encoding, then the characters are also changed to a specific desired Unicode standard.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to translate?  Most operating systems already use Unicode, and the keyboard mapping just determines the particular (Unicode) character for the physical key.  If you are talking about language translation, that’s not how it works.

Comment: You seem to be confusing language with encoding.  These days all languages are represented digitally by Unicode encoding, usually in utf-8 format.  The only purpose of the keylayout file is to give the typist access to extra chracters needed for a specific language.  The German keyboard produces just the same thing as the English keyboard, except it provides an easier way to input ß, ä, ö. ü.  There is nothing different about the way it is typed except how the fingers hit the keys, and you can type German perfectly fine wth the Mac US keyboard layout, it has all the required characters.

Comment: @TomGewecke This was an extremely helpful answer and if you write it up, it would be acceptable as an answer to be approved. Especially, if you might reference some material on the ISO standards. ISO standards for Unicode characters for each country, a list. A list referencing those characters that the german country would use, as a reference. I would like to know still if Apple store's these keyboard mappings in a specific location, otherwise. Your comments have been very helpful. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computers normally use a [single encoding system, ISO 10646/Unicode](https://home.unicode.org), that covers all languages at once.  It currently gives each of over 100,000 characters a unique idenfier.  All hardware keyboards are essentially the same as regards the codes sent to the computer, only the printing on the keys differs. Software keyboard layouts and input methods in MacOS provide mappings of the standard hardware keyboard output codes to the Unicode codepoints that reflect the requirements of any particular language, while fonts translate those codepoints into glyphs on the screen.

[This page](https://keyshorts.com/blogs/blog/37615873-how-to-identify-macbook-keyboard-localization) provides graphics of some of the different language mappings which you can select in MacOS via system preferences/keyboard/input sources.  These can be applied to any hardware keyboard and all use Unicode encoding.

These software mapping files are found in system/libary/keyboard layouts and system/library/input methods on a Mac.   Users can also create custom mappings with apps like Ukelele and Karabiner and other methods.

But I don’t offhand think such mapping files would play any role in a translation system of the sort you are describing.

Comment: appreciate the response. Thanks for answering my question.